# How to make an element fade in and bounce, from left?

Tags: css, keyframe

While learning C.S.S.3 animations and experimenting [Daniel Eden](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)'s, I tried to mix [two of those](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/tree/master/source) up : fadeInLeft and bounceInLeft.

If I got this right :

- The animation defined with a keyframes at-rule, I have to define its progress by setting its percentages up.
- translate3d got three parameters (the x, y and z axes respectively, may I presume).
- I have to call my animation's defined rule in the element, class or identifier I give to the H.T.M.L. tag I want to animate (this part is serious hxc business).

I had, after a first hardcore mix, something like :

```
@keyframes fade_in_and_bounce_from_left
{
    0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100%
    {
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }

    0%
    {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    }

    60%
    {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    }

    75%
    {
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }

    90%
    {
        transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    }

    100%
    {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: none;
    }
}

/* For length purposes, I just put the "uncommercialized" version of the rule. My code actually has all the needed vendor prefixes. */
```

… Which works just terribly if not at all. I then refined the code myself to make it fit my existing settings (such as reducing the -3000px value to the same as my H.T.M.L.'s body's width), removed transition-timing-function and added some more steps but the animation is now worse than ever (while the overall animation stays a good start for what I want, though).

What do I want ? An fading of an element from the left of my body tag (not html) to the right until its position where it stops but never in a straight manner, more in smooth bouncings.

The influenced part of my H.T.M.L. code looks as follows :

```
<!--[…]-->
        <article>
            <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_leftmost">
                <!--[…]-->
            </div>

            <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_left">
                <!--[…]-->
            </div>

            <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_right">
                <!--[…]-->
            </div>

            <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_rightmost">
                <!--[…]-->
            </div>
        </article>
<!--[…]-->

<!--Each of the "fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_x-x" classes calls the fade_in_and_bounce_from_left keyframe at-rule with only a different time so that document divisions arrive one after another from the left with a fading effect then bounce at a slightly decreasing speed from the rightmost to leftmost ones (so that each one is slower than the precedent) to their place in the page until the last.-->
```

I already checked that it was not an indentation problem.

The current look of my C.S.S. is a complete mess and produces worst results than those of the  original "hardcore mix", which is why I will not dump it here.
Could a good soul help me to give it the London look ?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle as well?

Comment: @Anubhav Done. http://jsfiddle.net/xmzxwhme/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was here ---> `animation: fade_in 0.25s linear 0 1 normal forwards running;`.

You don't need all that. Replace it with:

`animation: fade_in 0.25s 1;`

And you were missing the prefixes `-webkit-` and `-moz-`

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmzxwhme/3/)

```css
/* […] */

/* At-rules */
 @-webkit-keyframes fade_in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
 @-moz-keyframes fade_in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade_in_and_bounce_from_left {
    0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
        -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade_in_and_bounce_from_left {
    0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(25px, 0, 0);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translate3d(5px, 0, 0);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/* […] */

/* Elements */
 html {
    background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-color: rgb(54, 69, 79);
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    animation: fade_in 0.25s 1;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* […] */
 article {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
    background: url(160x90.jpg);
    width: 100%;
}
/* […] */

/* Classes */

/* […] */
 .latest_article_preview {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
    border-radius: 1px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 8px;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_leftmost {
    -webkit-animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.25s 1;
    animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.25s 1;
}
.fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_left {
    -webkit-animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.50s 1;
    animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.50s 1;
}
.fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_right {
    -webkit-animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.75s 1;
    animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 0.75s 1;
}
.fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_rightmost {
    -webkit-animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 1s 1;
    animation: fade_in_and_bounce_from_left 1s 1;
}
.latest_article_thumbnail {
}
.latest_article_start {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 8px;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.latest_article_headline {
    font-weight: bold;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.latest_article_lede {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
}

/* […] */
```

```html
<!--[…]-->

<body>
  <!--[…]-->

  <article>
    <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_leftmost">
      <span class="latest_article_thumbnail"><img src="160x90.jpg" alt="Approximative 16:9"></img></span>
      <div class="latest_article_start">
        <span class="latest_article_headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        <span class="latest_article_lede">Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehi</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_left">
      <span class="latest_article_thumbnail"><img src="160x90.jpg" alt="Approximative 16:9"></img></span>
      <div class="latest_article_start">
        <span class="latest_article_headline">Vivamus fermentum semper porta.</span>
        <span class="latest_article_lede">Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_right">
      <span class="latest_article_thumbnail"><img src="160x90.jpg" alt="Approximative 16:9"></img></span>
      <div class="latest_article_start">
        <span class="latest_article_headline">Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque.</span>
        <span class="latest_article_lede">Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibu</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="latest_article_preview fade_in_and_bounce_from_left_rightmost">
      <span class="latest_article_thumbnail"><img src="160x90.jpg" alt="Approximative 16:9"></img></span>
      <div class="latest_article_start">
        <span class="latest_article_headline">Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</span>
        <span class="latest_article_lede">In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hen</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <!--[…]-->
</body>
<!--[…]-->
```

Comment: Nice one, mate ! Thank you ! Still, as I said earlier, the portions of code I gave did not feature the vendor prefixes to shorten this post up. Oddly enough, with the appropriated vendor prefix, this does not work on Chromium properly. It works but kind of weirdly, not as in your snippet.

Comment: @RevoltXS - I'm guessing you are on a linux machine. If you are, you should know that they've released Chrome for linux.

Comment: @RevoltXS - It works perfectly fine on Chrome and Chromium, just checked. :)

Comment: I run on a Mac (which implies a Unix-based operating system) with a pre-built Chromium downloaded on a Blogspot website. There may an error somewhere else on my C.S.S. file or the pre-built Chromium is a bit faulty. It seems to work on Chrome, though so thank you.